# Is Semantic-UI + ReactJS available for a cave man?

Tags: html, reactjs, user-interface

I am a cave man in terms of web ui - I like it all without npm/nodejs and other nice infrastructure. I want it all in text files like in old days: include/link stuff from/to a HTML page and it's done. Is such cave approach possible for semantic-ui+ReactJS combination, meaning to have no npm/nodes/other server code for my front end to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always skip over using npm/nodejs/bundling by putting the 'packages' you want as script tags in the header of your html page. This still allows you to grab the extra libraries you want but means you don't need bundling and transpiling if you want to keep it simple. Like you mentioned, this is the way that used to be the standard and it still works just fine.

As an example, here is how to use react without a npm: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/huzuyen/edit?html,js,output)

Your HTML would look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.1.0/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.1.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</script>
</html>
```

Then the JS code for using react could look like:

```
const Child = () => <div>Child</div>

const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Parent
      <Child />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This answer is specifically for if you want to skip npm and bundling all together. I would definitely recommend checking out create-react-app if you are ok with having it do your config/bundling/transpiling for you.

Comment: more like [this](http://jsbin.com/cesupobiqa/edit?html,js,console,output) - you missed semantic-UI=)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is yes, that is if I am understanding your question. One of the ways you can use react (and any css lib, like Semantic UI), is to generate a static build that can be hosted very simply on any static hosting service (all text files, like in old days). however, it is common to use npm and node during development.

this is a useful tool to get started: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app